# Unable to force a script to retry for five times unless a 200 status in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a script using scrapy which is capable of retrying some links from a list recursively even when those links are invalid and get `404` response. I used `dont_filter=True` and `'handle_httpstatus_list': [404]` within `meta` to achieve the current behavior. What I'm trying to do now is let the script do the same for 5 times unless there is `200 status` in between. I've included `"max_retry_times":5` within `meta` considering the fact that it will keep retrying at most five times but it just retries infinitely.

I've tried so far:

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class StackoverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stackoverflow"
    start_urls = [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/taggedweb-scraping",
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/taggedweb-scraping"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,callback=self.parse,meta={"start_url":start_url,'handle_httpstatus_list': [404],"max_retry_times":5},dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self,response):
        if response.meta.get("start_url"):
            start_url = response.meta.get("start_url")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
        if soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
            for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
                title_link = response.urljoin(item.get("href"))
                print(title_link)

        else:
            print("++++++++++"*20) # to be sure about the recursion
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,meta={"start_url":start_url,'handle_httpstatus_list': [404],"max_retry_times":5},dont_filter=True,callback=self.parse)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0',
    })
    c.crawl(StackoverflowSpider)
    c.start()
```

***How can I let the script keep retrying at most five times?***

***Note***: There are multiple urls in the list which are identical. I don't wish to kick out the duplicate links. I would like to let scrapy use all of the urls.

Comment: Just a comment here, you don't need bs4 when you're using scrapy. You could simply `response.css(".summary .question-hyperlink::attr(href)").getall()`. [Check Scrapy docs for more info on selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Comment: Thanks @Thiago Curvelo for the pointer. I'm already aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can propose following directions:
1.
add `404` code to [`RETRY_HTTP_CODES`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-http-codes) setting as it doesn't include response code `404` by default.

> is capable of retrying a link recursively even when the link is invalid and get 404 response

```
class StackoverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stackoverflow"
    custom_settings = {
        'RETRY_HTTP_CODES' : [500, 502, 503, 504, 522, 524, 408, 429 , 404],
        'RETRY_TIMES': 5 # usage of "max_retry_times" meta key is also valid
    }
....
```

2. with `dont_filter=True` - scrapy application will visit previously visited pages. 
   removing  `dont_filter=True` from your code should solve infinite loop issue

> but it just retries infinitely.

Comment: Your solution seems to be working in the right way. What if two such identical links in the list? Should I not stick with `dont_filter=True` so that scrapy uses both of the identical links?

Comment: If You have two identical urls in `start_urls` and if there is no `dont_filter=True` in `start_requests` method - request to only first url will be called, second url will be filtered.as duplicate

Comment: 3.keep `dont_filter=True` and add [`DEPTH_LIMIT`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit) setting. In this case application will not filter duplicate links and in the same time it will not have endless lopp due to depth limitation.

Comment: It seems promising @Georgiy. Could you help me comply with this approach as it is foreign to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class StackoverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stackoverflow"
    start_urls = [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/taggedweb-scraping",
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/taggedweb-scraping"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,callback=self.parse,meta={"request_count":0,'handle_httpstatus_list': [404],"max_retry_times":5},dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self,response):
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
        if soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
            for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
                title_link = response.urljoin(item.get("href"))
                print(title_link)

        else:
            request_count = response.meta.get("request_count")
            max_retry_times = response.meta.get("max_retry_times")
            if request_count < max_retry_times :
                start_url = response.url
                request_count += 1    
                yield scrapy.Request(start_url,meta={"request_count":request_count,'handle_httpstatus_list': [404],"max_retry_times":max_retry_times },dont_filter=True,callback=self.parse)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0',
    })
    c.crawl(StackoverflowSpider)
    c.start()
```

I think so. please let me know your opinion if I had mistakes.

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about scrapy, so I apologise if this solution will not work.

But for a simple counter I've found a while loop works well. It would look something like this:

```
x = 5
while not x == 0:
    for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,callback=self.parse,meta={"start_url":start_url,'handle_httpstatus_list': [404],"max_retry_times":5},dont_filter=True)
    # 200 status check goes here using an if statement that results in a break statement if true
    x -= 1
```

So you perform the action that you wish to perform, then minus 1 from your counter. the action loops through again and again and you minus one from your counter. This repeats until your counter reaches zero, at which point your while loop breaks and you stop looping through your code.

To add a check for `200 status` you add an if check into your code, which I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do, and place it before `x -= 1`. If the `200 status` is `True` you add a break statement to exit the while loop. Alternatively if you want to use the `x` counter later on in your code (say you are running through several different function checks) you could use `x = 0` before your break statement.

Again, I don't know anything about scrapy yet, so I apologize if this is not a suitable solution.